# What number am I?

Tags: mathematics

I am not divisible by anything, but there's a formula to find my value.

I have a 9 in the ten-billionths place.

Multiply me by $d$ to get $c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> $\pi$

---

> Multiply me by $d$ to get $c$.

Pi times the diameter of a circle is the circumference.

> I have a 9 in the ten-billionths place.

Pi's decimal value is 3.141592653589...

> there's a formula to solve my value.

There are a number of [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Continued_fractions) that evaluate to $\pi$.